# How to access text files written by Java app inside docker

Tags: java, docker, executable-jar

I have Java app writing some output files to the user home directory.
I built a docker image for this Java app and ran the docker container.
I also added logs to my program to see where the file gets saved.

```
Writing the metadata to the file path /root/39fd75837c864a68a8db42442d4401fa.txt
```

When I run `docker run -it imageId bash` and tried to access the above file in the container but was unable to find it.

Where do these files get saved and how to access those files inside the docker container?

Comment: use `docker exec -it container_id bash` and check. Right now you are lanuching new image, not connecting to the existing container.

Comment: In the future, you probably should use a volume or bind mount and write your data there. Otherwise, when the container you're running exits, the data you've written will be gone.

Comment: `docker run` will start a new instance of the container so that won't help you. [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) is what you want - copy the files locally. Otherwise `docker exec` into the system and view the files remotely. But a more appropriate solution is to add a `VOLUME` directive in the `Dockerfile` and write the logs there. Then mount that volume somewhere locally with `-v`.

Comment: thanks for the help, I did add sleep to the docker image to not to exit after the run, but adding volume makes sense.

Comment: you could also run your container as daemon (-d option) such that when you exit - it runs (until you stop it)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you run `docker run` command, docker creates a new container. In order to be able to access your files you either need access the same container or persist the files across containers on a volume.

If you run a container with `docker run -it imageId bash` command, the container will shut down as soon as you exit from it. Therefore, consider running it as daemon (`-d` option) - in this case container will keep running once you exit from it.

Second option would be to start the same container and attach to it with exec command:

```sh
docker start my_container
```

Attaching to the running container with exec command:

```sh
docker exec -it my_container bash
```

Or you can simply copy the files from running container, using `docker cp`

The third option is to attach a volume persisting the files:

```sh
docker run -v /app/data:/data imageId
```